# Creating tiled clones that are spaced 10px apart horizontally in Inkscape?

Tags: inkscape

I drew a diagonal line with the Bezier tool and I want to create 10 tiled clones of it horizontally in a row and they should overlap.  So if the first original tile is at 0,0, then the next on starts at 0, 10px, and the next one at 0, 20px, and so on.

Trying to figure out how to do it with the `Edit > Clone > Create Tiled Clones` tool, or perhaps there is a better option?

Comment: For such a task, have you tried to duplicate the path (Ctrl-D) and use the [transform tool](http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/html/Transforms.html) to move the copy? It seems simpler. I've not found a way to use tiled clones with px units, see also [this](https://alpha.inkscape.org/vectors/www.inkscapeforum.com/viewtopiccf7b.html?t=18000).

Comment: The settings for moving cloned tiles are in percentages, so you'd need to work out the X percentage of the move based on the X dimension of your object. So, not really going to be easy to get an accurate 10px move for each clone. To be honest it might be easier to just enable the grid, create a clone, and duplicate and place the clones with snapping to grid enabled. If you think this would work for you, I can add it as an answer.

Comment: Thanks guys - that's what I though.  I'll probably just use a grid and draw the lines / copy them out manually or use the transform tool.  Thanks again for the suggestions.